# List all files / binaries in current PATH

Tags: bash, ls, path, autocomplete

Is there an "easy" way of running an "ls -la" style command for listing all files / executable binaries in the current PATH?

(I intend to pipe the output into grep, for looking for commands with unknown prefixes but basically known "names", the kind of case when the auto-completion / tabbing in bash is essentially useless. So some sort of an "inverse auto-complete feature" ...)

Comment: Can you give examples? How will it different with `ls -la`?

Comment: "ls -la"/"ls -a" does only list files in your current directory (pwd). I want to list all (executable) files in all directories included in PATH.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
compgen -c # will list all the commands you could run.
compgen -a # will list all the aliases you could run.
compgen -b # will list all the built-ins you could run.
compgen -k # will list all the keywords you could run.
compgen -A function # will list all the functions you could run.
compgen -A function -abck # will list all the above in one go.
```

Comment: Nice, this is very much what I have been looking for. It even includes executable binaries in the current directory. Thanks.

Comment: Works well... in bash.

Comment: is there a way to list the path of each of these without doing `which $(compgen -A function -abck)`?

Comment: I couldn't find any better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that lists the content of the directories `$PATH`. If passed arguments, the function only lists commands whose name contaisn one of the arguments. The arguments are interpreted as glob patterns.

```
shopt -s extglob
lspath () {
  local IFS pattern
  IFS='|'
  pattern="*@($*)*"
  IFS=':'
  for d in $PATH; do
    for x in "$d/"$pattern; do
      [ "$x" = "$d/$pattern" ] || echo "${x##*/}"
    done
  done | sort -u
}
```

Like many things, this is easier in zsh.

```
lspath () {
  (($#)) || set ''
  print -lr -- $^path/*$^@*(N:t) | sort -u
}
```

The `^` character in [parameter expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) causes the text concatenated with the array to be added to each array element, e.g. `path=(/bin /usr/bin); echo $^path/foo` prints `/bin/foo /usr/bin/foo`.
`/*$^@*` looks like a comic book insult but is in fact the ordinary character `/`, the wildcard `*`, the special parameter `$@` (the array of positional parameter) with the `^` modifier, and again `*`.
`(N:t)` is the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `N` to get an empty expansion if there is no match followed by the [history modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) `t` to keep only the basename (“tail”) of each match.

More cryptic, avoids the external call but this is only of cosmetic interest:

```
lspath () {
  (($#)) || set ''
  local names; names=($^path/*$^@*(N:t))
  print -lr -- ${(ou)names}
}
```

You may in fact be looking for the [`apropos`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/apropos) command, which searches for man pages of commands whose short description contains a keyword. A limitation is that this only find commands that have a man page.

Comment: In the zsh function, the second `^` seems to result in no output for a "no arguments" call? If you drop it, you could list them all, and still search for single keywords (but not a list of them). The `(Non:t)` seems to say that asterisks should be expanded? Couldn't figure that last one out.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg Right, thanks for the fix. I've added an explanation of the line noise.

Comment: OK, let's see: If there are no arguments, you set "them" to nothing, because what was there (when there wasn't any), still somehow was disruptive of what you did next? Also, I've never seen lowercase `path`, but when I run it in the shell, it is indeed $PATH but with spaces instead of `:`. The rest is crystal clear :)

Comment: @EmanuelBerg No: if there are no arguments, I set the array of arguments to be a one-element array containing the empty string. This way, no arguments means every name containing the empty string matches, i.e. every name matches. `$path` is a zsh feature: it's a [tied parameter](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset), an array that is automatically updated when `PATH` is updated and vice versa.

Comment: Aha, now I see! Wow, that was unorthodox!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $(echo $PATH | sed -e 's/\:/\ /g'); do find "$i" -perm +rwx -exec echo {} \; 2> /dev/null; done
```

first we echo `$PATH` into sed and replace ":" with " ".

then we do a find on each of those things to find files with rwx and echo them.

`2> /dev/null` is so `find` won't print errors

Comment: you need a `-maxdepth 1` and `-type f` in your find, else you'll find subdirectories and their files (which PATH search won't). Also, your permission test is weird—should just for `+x`, I'd think?

Comment: This won't handle the edge cases were a valid blank entry is the same as '.', for example `:/bin` or `/bin::/usr/bin`.  Try adding `s/::/:.:/;s/^:/.:/;s/:$/:./` to the `sed` command.

Comment: Actually `find` can search more paths, so you can do it without the loop: `find $(echo $PATH | sed -e 's/\:/\ /g') -perm +rwx …` Of course, directory names containing spaces will mess it up, but the loop based one has the same problem anyway.

Comment: @manatwork you're right.  I added quotes to solve that issue just now

Comment: Sorry, that solves nothing. The problem is with replacing the colons with spaces to allow word splitting. So you transform “/foo bar:/fiz baz” into “/foo bar /fiz baz” then pass that to `for`. So `for` will loop over a list of 4 words. To manipulate word splitting better set the `IFS` according to your need: `IFS=':'; find $PATH -perm +rwx …`.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see now. coffee is kicking in, finally.

Comment: Might also use bash string substitution `find ${PATH//:/ } -maxdepth 1 -type f`  (will not work with spaces in dirs though)

Answer (score 1):

```
function findinpath () { 
   OLDIFS="$IFS" ; 
   IFS="$(printf ':\t\n')" ; 
   for regexp in "$@" ; do 
      for adir in $PATH ; do 
         find "$adir" -perm -111 -a ! -type d -ls 2>/dev/null | grep -i "/[^/]*$regexp"
      done ; 
   done ; 
   IFS="$OLDIFS" ; 
}
```

the find only matches that  : have at least one "x" (executable) bit set, and that is not a directory.

and use it with a list of regexp to be found:

```
findinpath awk sed '\.sh$'
```

Comment: regexp "." will show you everything

Comment: with the regular IFS, you can find duplicate entries in your $PATH with : `echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | sort  | uniq -d`

Comment: I tried the code for all the answers and this is the only one that actually gave me what I was looking for (full paths to every instance of a given command on the PATH).

Comment: I m glad it helped :)